# Finding average according to column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Screenshot of example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePAO3.jpg)

I have a table with the first column of names and the first row of events and scores of each event filled in.  There are ~50 columns and rows, but I simplified the picture for clarity.  I am looking to find the average of each name for the respective events.  So cell I2 would be 3.5, because Alex scored 2 and 5 points, but cell I4 should be 5 since Chris only competed "Event A" 1 time and got 5 points.

I tried doing something like this as a start for cell I2, but it's obviously wrong.

=COUNTIF(B$1:OFFSET(B$1,0,(COUNT(B2:G2)-1)),"A")

I feel like I'm missing an easy solution like a combination of lookup or if statements or something like that.

Thank you for any help or insight!

EDIT: Wow I'm so silly aren't I.... just found the AVERAGEIFS function. All it took was me writing my problem and talking myself through it.

Comment: Wow I'm so silly aren't I.... just found the AVERAGEIFS function.  All it took was me writing my problem and talking myself through it.